# How to show categories total in labels using highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to show the total in xAxis labels (categories) in the following [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xadp7qwt/2/):

```
    ...
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return this.value + ' (' + 'total?' + ')';
            }
        }
    },
    ...
```

Someone knows how could I get the total there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that `total` and all other points are not yet generated, so you need to calculate total on your own, for example:

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                var index = this.axis.categories.indexOf(this.value),
                    sum = 0;

                $.each(this.axis.series, function(i, s) {
                   sum += s.options.data[index]; 
                });

                return this.value + ' (' + sum + ')';
            }
        }
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jnkpvreL/